# Google login to vuejs application using aws cognito user pools

Tags: amazon-cognito

I have simple vuejs application and I use vue-google-signin-button plugin to login via google. That works correctly.

To login by user name and password I use aws cognito user pools. Which also works.

Is it possible to login via google and store logged in user in to user pool? I checked plenty of aws manuals but I haven't found such option.

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at AWS cognito social providers login: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-configuring-federation-with-social-idp.html

Comment: Thanks Joaquin, I did it already, but there's missing some details regarding the implementation, that article looks only as an intro. And for more information it routes to: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-social.html where's only back link to the current article. Don't you have some example please or so? Thank you.